# Get the value of the object using the string index in ts and continue to access it

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
interface IpPatientAddressDto {
  ...
  addressSeq: number;
}

interface IpPatientInfoDto {
  ...
  localAddress: IpPatientAddressDto;
}

const originalPatient:IpPatientInfoDto  = {
  ...
  localAddress:{
     addressSeq:0001
  }
}

 const createAddrCollectionObj = (prop: keyof IpPatientInfoDto) => {
      return {
         addressSeq: originalPatient[prop].addressSeq,  // error:TS2339      
      }
 }

const a1 = createAddrCollectionObj('localAddress');
```

How do I need to define prop?

typescript error:TS2339: Property  addressSeq  does not exist on type
string | number | Date | IpPatientAddressDto | IpPatientRelationshipDto[]
Property  addressSeq  does not exist on type  string

I know the way to write it, but I don't want to provide extra ways to get it.

```
const get = <T extends keyof ObjType>(key: T): ObjType[T] => {
    return obj[key]
}
let res = get("a"); //"1"
```

What I imagine is that createAddrCollectionObj is type constrained by the prop parameter, and the createAddrCollectionObj method must have access to other properties such as addressSeq.

When calling createAddrCollectionObj('xxx'), ts can identify whether xxx matches the corresponding type.

```
  const createAddrCollectionObj = (prop: keyof IpPatientInfoDto) => {
     const property = originalPatient[prop];
     if (!isIpPatientAddressDto(property,prop)) {
       return null;
     }
     return {
       addressSeq: property.addressSeq,
       patientSeq: property.patientSeq,
       address: patInfo[prop + 'Details'],
       provinceCode: patInfo[prop][0].code,
       provinceName: patInfo[prop][0].name,
       cityCode: patInfo[prop][1].code,
       cityName: patInfo[prop][1].name,
       areaCode: patInfo[prop][2].code,
       areaName: patInfo[prop][2].name,
       zipCode: '', // 邮编
     };
   };
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the logic here. What if the user passes a different key to `createAddrCollectionObj`, a key that doesn't have that property? That's what TS is warning you about.

Comment: How do I tell ts that prop is some key for the originalPatient?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please [edit] your code to be a [mre] that demonstrates your issue when we copy and paste it into our own IDEs.  Pseudocode and missing  declarations make it difficult to get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a key check so the type system can know what the property type is. All it knows is you're passing a key of `IpPatientInfoDto` but there are other properties that do not have type `IpPatientAddressDto`.

```
const createAddrCollectionObj = (prop: keyof IpPatientInfoDto) => {
    switch (prop)
    {
        case 'localAddress': // originalPatient['localAddress'] is IpPatientAddressDto
            return {
                addressSeq: originalPatient[prop].addressSeq,
            };
        // other cases...
        default:
            return {
                addressSeq: null,
            };
    }
 };
```

Comment: Ha ha, you're right, but can typescript be made smarter in some way, perhaps starting with defining prop types?

Comment: It can only be as smart as the information you give it. Otherwise the language is making decisions for you. You need to constrain the type down as specific as you can (and generics usually can help with that).

Answer (score 0):

Only the property `localAdress` has an object with an `addressSeq` property. TS is helping you avoid the mistake of accessing a property that may not exist.

What you can do is use a Type Guard to check if the object has the shape you expect to have like this:

```
function isIpPatientAddressDto(obj: IpPatientInfoDto[keyof IpPatientInfoDto]): obj is IpPatientAddressDto {
  return obj.hasOwnProperty('addressSeq');
}

const createAddrCollectionObj = (prop: keyof IpPatientInfoDto) => {
  const property = originalPatient[prop];
  if (!isIpPatientAddressDto(property)) {
    return {
      addressSeq: defaultValue, //defaultValue needs to be defined elsewhere   
    };
  }

  return {
    addressSeq: property.addressSeq   
  }
}

const a1 = createAddrCollectionObj('localAddress');
```

In that way, you check if the property exists first or return a default value if it doesn't.

Comment: But it may return null, and from a code perspective, it is normal to understand that it should not be null, because the object is already given. Doing so will cause null to be processed elsewhere. Can you use assertions to solve the null problem

Comment: Well, it depends of what do you want to handle that case. Maybe you can return a default object, I will update the answer using that.